# Thread NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, render

Hey whenever i run this error output.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GraphicsTest.render(GraphicsTest.java:50)
    at GraphicsTest.run(GraphicsTest.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

here is the code i cant figure out why it will not work. i have searched online and cant seem to find any answers. i am new and just wanna draw an image to the screen. then maybe try and create a bufferedImage array later on but that is looking like it will be awhile down the road haha. thanks in advance for any help :)

```
public class GraphicsTest extends JPanel implements Runnable{

public static BufferedImage image;
private boolean isRunning = false;

public void start() {
    isRunning = true;
    new Thread(this).start();

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    GraphicsTest I = new GraphicsTest();

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Test Rendering");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);

    I.start();

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("Grap/roby.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void render() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(isRunning) {

        render();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please post specifically what line 50 is. Read about NullPointerExceptions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: A thought: consider reading a tutorial or two on Swing graphics before guessing how to do it. There are issues with your code that suggest that you've not yet done this important step. The [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) link will get you started.

Comment: Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Swing uses a passive rendering engine, while you can make "suggestions" to the rendering engine, you are, ultimately, not responsible for the rendering process.  `getGraphics` is not how painting works in Swing and it can return `null`.  You might like to also have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 2):

> and just wanna draw an image to the screen

Try using something like...

```
GraphicsTest gt = new GraphicsTest();

try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("Grap/roby.png"));
    I.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JFrame window = new JFrame("Test Rendering");
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.add(gt);
window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
```

Take a look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details.

Never use `getGraphics` to try and do custom painting, this is not how painting works in Swing.

If you're really intersted in knowing how painting works, take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others